# Why does ffmpeg cmake external project is not working

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg with h264 support as an external cmake project. But after compile it, I'm getting libavcodec reference errors.

The compile problem is occurring on Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have installed all dependencies for ffmpeg and also libx264-dev.

Cmake external project

```
set( proj ffmpeg )
set( SHARED_FFMPEG )


set(BASIC
        --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
        --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include
        --enable-gpl
        --enable-libx264)


option( FFMPEG_GPL "Use a GPL version of FFMPEG" OFF )

set(FFMPEG_INSTALL_DIR  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/INSTALL )

ExternalProject_Add(${proj}
        # Set up dirs
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${proj}
        INSTALL_DIR ${FFMPEG_INSTALL_DIR}
        # get the project
        GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git"
        GIT_TAG "n3.2.13"

        # Build the project
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1

        # Configure step
        # DO STH FOR THE ARCHITECTURE...
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --prefix=${FFMPEG_INSTALL_DIR} ${SHARED_FFMPEG} ${FFMPEG_GPL_FLAG} ${BASIC}

        #  BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -j${NProcessors}
        )

# define the library suffix
if( SUPER_SHARED_LIBS )
    if( APPLE )
        set(LIBRARY_SUFFIX .dylib)
    else( APPLE )
        set(LIBRARY_SUFFIX .so)
    endif( APPLE )
else( SUPER_SHARED_LIBS )
    set(LIBRARY_SUFFIX .a)
endif( SUPER_SHARED_LIBS )

# ADD DIRECTORIES FOR DEPENDENCIES IN Main/CMakeLists.txt
set( FFMPEG_LIBRARYS libavcodec.a
        libavformat.a
        libavutil.a
        libswscale.a
        )

include_directories(${FFMPEG_INSTALL_DIR}/include)

set(FFMPEG_LIBRARY_DIRS ${FFMPEG_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/)
link_directories(${FFMPEG_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

C++ Where I used the library

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/mathematics.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"

#define INBUF_SIZE 4096
#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096
}

...

 fReceiveBuffer = new u_int8_t[DUMMY_SINK_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    fReceiveBufferAV = new u_int8_t[DUMMY_SINK_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE+4];
    fReceiveBufferAV[0] = 0;
    fReceiveBufferAV[1] = 0;
    fReceiveBufferAV[2] = 0;
    fReceiveBufferAV[3] = 1;


    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
    avpkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    avpkt.pts = avpkt.dts = 0;

    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
    avpkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    avpkt.pts = avpkt.dts = 0;

    /* set end of buffer to 0 (this ensures that no overreading happens for damaged mpeg streams) */
    memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);

    //codec = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

...
```

Error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/awesom-o
/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/INSTALL/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_frame':
/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:280: undefined reference to `x264_picture_init'
/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/INSTALL/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `reconfig_encoder':
/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:266: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/INSTALL/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_frame':
/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:340: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
```

Comment: "I have installed all dependencies for ffmpeg and also libx264-dev." - I don't see in your code linking with `libx264.a`. Exactly this library provides missed symbols.

Comment: I think "--enable-libx264" and "--extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib" does that. It was installed using apt get, so it is inside /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Yes, `libx264` is uses when `ffmpeg` is built. But when you **link** your application with `ffmpeg`, you need to repeat linking with all required libraries. This is a downside of the **static** libraries, as they don't remember their original linking. (Actually, when static libraries are created, they are not linked at all).

Comment: target_link_libraries(APP_CORE ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}pthread swresample m z x264), and the exact same error happen.

Comment: Hm, actually `ffmpeg` is compiled with **its own version** of `libx264`. You may find that from the error log: the file `/home/tiburcio/CLionProjects/awesom-o/cmake-build-debug/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c` is a part of `libavcoded.a` library you use. As you have `libx264` already installed, its headers may conflict with the version shipped with `ffmpeg`. Try to remove your package `libx264-dev` and rebuild ffmpeg. See also that thread: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/problem-with-enable-libx264-option-in-ffmpeg-822156/.